# Logging request headers sent to Amazon S3 accelerated endpoint for uploads

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've an Amazon S3 bucket where I have enabled [Transfer Acceleration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/transfer-acceleration.html). I am uploading files via PUT request directly from JavaScript to the bucket using the transfer acceleration end-point.

99% of the uploads happen fine (I've the necessary CORS setup etc.) but a small fraction of the uploads fail and I want to investigate why they fail. For that, I want to log the request headers sent to the S3 upload end-point. How do I do that? I already tried enabling request logging to the S3 bucket but they don't have the request headers of the original PUT request.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable  cloud watch  events try see in cloud watch logs